# Verifying if a word is reserved in Microsoft Access SQL using c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, oledb

I am building a DAL class for my school project.
The main Idea is for it to be generic.
Everything is fine until I get to the reserved words part.
I made a method that works with "Password", Which is a reserved word

```
       public static void AddRow(string name, object[] values)
    {
        string com = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM " + name;
        DataTable dt = OleDbhelper.fill(com);
        if (dt.Columns.Count - 1 == values.Length)
        {
            string sql = "INSERT INTO " + name + " (";
            for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "Password")
                    sql += "[";
                sql += dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
                if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "Password")
                    sql += "]";
                if (i != dt.Columns.Count - 1)
                    sql += ",";
                else
                    sql += ") ";
            }
            sql += "VALUES (";
            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Columns[i + 1].DataType.ToString() == "System.String")
                    sql += "'" + values[i].ToString() + "'";
                else
                    sql += values[i].ToString();
                if (i != dt.Columns.Count - 2)
                    sql += ",";
                else
                    sql += ") ";
            }
            OleDbhelper.Execute(sql);
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is to replace the

```
if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "Password")
```

Line into a something that will work with all the reserved words ("Level" for example).
I've been checking the internet and tried different methods for hours now, but i still cant find a way to do it.
I also can't find a full updated list, only partially made lists that contain only part of the reserved words.

I'm lost here. I'll gladly accept any ideas of how to fix this problem.

Comment: why not just put `[]` s around the column and table names whether it is reserved or not? `sql += "[" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "]";`

Comment: @Rhumborl the idea is that the Method will work for any Table. So I need it to find by itself if its reserved

Comment: yes exactly - putting brackets around a non-reserved word doesn't break anything - `select * from MyRandomTableName` is the same as `select * from [MyRandomTableName]`

Comment: @Rhumborl so what you're saying is to just put [] around every word?

Comment: yes thats all you need to do

Comment: @Rhumborl: Please re-post your comments as an answer, so that it can be upvoted and accepted. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to check if the column name is a reserved word to decide whether to put `[]`s around it or not. It is safe to just add brackets whatever the name, this does not break anything.

So this part of the code:

```
if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "Password")
    sql += "[";
sql += dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
if (dt.Columns[i].ColumnName == "Password")
    sql += "]";
```

can just be rewritten as:

```
sql += "[" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "]";
```